# How can I calculate a combination of limit and sum?

Tags: equation-solving

[image]

How can I solve the above problem?

I enter it as:

```
Limit[Sum[Sqrt[1 + i^2/n^2]/n, {i, n}], n -> Infinity]
```

but this is not working:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the sum converges ? Because I am not .. Anyway, that's easily found in the docs.

Comment: The limit is infinity but Mathematica does not recognize that and thus returns unevaluated.

Comment: For a practical result try manually converging the upper and lower bounds seen here: `Plot[Sum[Sqrt[1 + i^2/n^2]/N[n], {i, 1, n}], {n, 1, 20}]`

Comment: I voted to reopen as a recent edit by the OP changed the interpretation of this question. It's not about typesetting, but about solving the limit.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Although true in other cases, it's not possible in cases like this when the terms depend on the upper index. Had mathematica been able to evaluate the `Sum[..., {i,n}]` then the `Limit` approach would have had a chance to work. (I'm sure you know this, just thought it was worth clarifying the question in general)

Comment: Oops. Per @ChrisDegnan, it does converge. My mistake. The underlying issue remains that `Sum` does not find a closed form, and `Limit` cannot do anything useful with the unevalauted `Sum`.

Answer (score 9):

In the limit $n\to\infty$ the sum is the integral (it's just the [Riemann sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum))

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{1}{n}\sqrt{1+\frac{i^2}{n^2}}=\int_0^1\sqrt{1+x^2}dx
$$
where $dx$ is $1/n$ with $n \to \infty$.

```
Integrate[Sqrt[1 + x^2], {x, 0, 1}]
% // TrigToExp
%% // N
```

> ```
> 1/2 (Sqrt[2] + ArcSinh[1])
> 1/Sqrt[2] + 1/2 Log[1 + Sqrt[2]]
> 1.14779
> ```

Comment: Nice observation!

Comment: +1 - looks really good. Haven't figured it all out yet though.

Answer (score 1):

This sum does not converge since if you drop the $\frac{i^2}{n^2}$ you get the harmonic series which does not converge and since the lower limit does not converge this sum shouldn't converge either.

Comment: its not clear to me what he asking.. but FWIW you can put Infinity as the iterator limit in the sum.

Comment: It appears to converge within limits `1.1465 < x < 1.148`, although it might diverge for n beyond 1000.

Comment: The sum is over `i` not `n`, so one does not get the harmonic series

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear to me that `Limit` and `Sum` can be combined, but trying some plotting :-

[image]

```
f[n_] := Sum[Sqrt[1 + i^2/n^2]/N[n], {i, 1, n}]
data = Table[{n, f[n]}, {n, 1, 10000, 1}];
ListLinePlot[data]
```

[image]

Comment: You could sample at only integer values, that get rids of the jiggling

Comment: I just realised that.  Made edit ;-)